# Статические сборки QT

Tags: qt

2 дня компиляции это долго... Может кто уже собирает основные релизы?

Comment: а на чем вы компилируете, что у вас два дня занимает?) когда-то брал тут https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/windows/, но сайт устарел. что-то нагуглилось тут: https://github.com/martinrotter/qt5-minimalistic-builds но не использовал. Думаю отсутствие билдов связано с ограничениями лицензии, кьют все больше становится платным

Comment: он изначально был платным) компилирую полную версию с mingw 32 бит на windows 10 на виртуалке